# How to trigger the Refund Notification email

Tags: message-templates

There is a message template called "Additional Payment Receipt or Refund Notification" in the System workflow messages. I have tried to trigger the Refund Notification by adding contributions and then setting their status to be "Refunded" and I thought this would trigger the email notification, but it didn't. I have tried with event registrations too, but got no email. Am I doing something wrong, or did I miss a step? I couldn't find any information about the refund email notification in the CiviCRM guide either. I have tried on 4.6.33 and 4.7.27 installations but doesn't seem to work on any of them.

Let me know please if you have the answer. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

The Additional Payment Receipt or Refund Notification template is used to send receipt when payment is recorded for `Partially paid` or `Pending refund` or `Pending Pay Later` Contribution.

To trigger this you will need to create Pending Paylater Contribution and then under Contribution tab of Contact or Find Contribution results click on `More >> Record Payment` besides the contribution row. 
[image]

Submit the Payment form by checking `Automatically email a receipt to xxx ??`
[image]

HTH

Pradeep

Comment: Hello Pradeep! Thanks for your answer! Yes I get a receipt of the contribution with that, but if I set any payment to refunded status, there is no email generated still. So the problem is not with the successful payment email, its with the refund email. I thought it should be triggered every time a contribution is set to Refunded status.